# How can I write/read ontology model to a tdb?

Tags: rdf, jena, owl

I'm new to Apache Jena. I want to write/read ontology model to a tdb, so a wrote a small trunk of code to test it:

```
private static void basicOntology() {
    OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
    m.setNsPrefix("graph", NS);
    OntClass thingClass = m.createClass(NS + "THING");
    thingClass.addComment("a", "b");
    OntClass klass = m.createClass(NS + "POI");
    klass.addSuperClass(thingClass);
    Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset("/tmp/someThings");
    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
    dataset.addNamedModel("ontology", m);
    dataset.commit();
}
```

But it gives me this exception stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jena.tdb.store.DatasetPrefixesTDB.readPrefix(DatasetPrefixesTDB.java:86)
at org.apache.jena.sparql.graph.GraphPrefixesProjection.get(GraphPrefixesProjection.java:101)
at org.apache.jena.sparql.graph.GraphPrefixesProjection.set(GraphPrefixesProjection.java:79)
at org.apache.jena.shared.impl.PrefixMappingImpl.setNsPrefix(PrefixMappingImpl.java:75)
at org.apache.jena.shared.impl.PrefixMappingImpl.setNsPrefixes(PrefixMappingImpl.java:163)
at org.apache.jena.shared.impl.PrefixMappingImpl.setNsPrefixes(PrefixMappingImpl.java:130)
at org.apache.jena.graph.GraphUtil.addInto(GraphUtil.java:137)
at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.DatasetGraphTriplesQuads.addGraph(DatasetGraphTriplesQuads.java:80)
at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.DatasetGraphWrapper.addGraph(DatasetGraphWrapper.java:94)
at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.DatasetImpl.addNamedModel(DatasetImpl.java:158)
at com.sankuai.ai.kg.jena.Main.basicOntology(Main.java:31)
at com.sankuai.ai.kg.jena.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

Comment: `dataset.addNamedModel("ontology", m);` expects a URI as first argument. Javadoc is [online](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/Dataset.html#addNamedModel-java.lang.String-org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model-) as usual and the best friend of a Java developer.

Comment: The string "ontology" is a valid URI, and also IRI. The problem, perhaps, in configuration or broken tbd store. Checked locally with jena 3.6.0 - everything is working. What version of jena-* is used?

Comment: Please be careful with your statement here...*The string "ontology" is a valid URI* - ehm, no - by definition, this is clearly not a URI. It might be resolved using a base URI, ok. But "ontology" is for sure **not** a valid URI, or where do you see the non-empty scheme? And the colon is where?

Comment: [this line](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-tdb/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/tdb/store/DatasetPrefixesTDB.java#L86) causes the NPE, check your prefixes.